# TikZ dash pattern generates an offending PDF

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, debugging

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\dotsize{1}
\def\spacesize{2}
\def\linesize{4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  dash pattern=%
  on \dotsize  pt off \spacesize pt on \dotsize  pt off \spacesize pt on \dotsize  pt %
  off \spacesize %
  on \linesize pt off \spacesize pt on \linesize pt off \spacesize pt on \linesize pt %
  off \spacesize pt,%
  orange]
  \draw (0,0) -- (4cm,4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code compiles just fine and I can open it using both `skim` and `acrobat reader`. However, when trying to print the PDF using `skim` I get the following error:

```
 ERROR: limitcheck
 OFFENDING COMMAND: setdash

 STACK:

 0
 [0.99628 1.99255 0.99628 1.99255 0.99628 1.99255 3.9851 1.99255 3.9851 1.99255 3.9851 1.99255]
```

**printed** on the page. When printing from `acrobat` I get the expected printout.

I'm using `MacTeX` and `TikZ` 2.10-CVS.

Two questions:

1. Can someone reproduce the issue?
2. How can I debug this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in skim.

Comment: Since it works with Adobe's software the PDF is likely correct and the problem is in your PDF viewer or your printing application (CUPS).

Comment: Update: Seems to be an issue of PDFKit (https://sourceforge.net/p/skim-app/bugs/975/). I submitted a bug report to Apple as well.